# Start transaction, commit and rollback Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have a question: Does anybody know if the Db class (PS v1.6.0.20) manages the mysql transaction?

```
//Begin
$db->insert('product', array());
$db->insert('product_lang', array());
$db->insert('product_shop', array());
//Complete
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For "insert" no.

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('
                    INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_invoice_payment` (`id_order_invoice`, `id_order_payment`, `id_order`)
                    VALUES('.(int)$invoice->id.', '.(int)$payment->id.', '.(int)$order->id.')');
```

Db class just manage select queries.